# supervisord - multiple environment variables

Tags: configuration, supervisord

I have a supervisord configuration file where I need to set multiple environment variables.

E.g.

```
environment=A="1",B="2",C="3", etc.
```

Is there a way of writing this in the file so that it spans multiple lines.

Something like...

```
environment=
A="1",
B="2",
C="3"
```

There are quite a lot of values and I would prefer not to write them all on a single line, if it can be avoided.

Comment: What happened when you tried that? Some squinting at the supervisor docs and then the ConfigParser docs and then RFC 822 of all places indicates that form may be correct.

Comment: Sorry, found out the problem. My variables were not indented in my file. I did write it correctly purely by chance in this question though. D'oh! I've updated the question to better reflect the actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

The trouble was that I was not indenting the variables in my file. The way I suggested in this question turned out to actually be correct. You can separate multiple environment variables on separate lines, but they MUST be indented. I used a tab character and it worked correctly.

e.g.

```
environment=
    A="",
    B="",
    C=""
```

Updated the question's sample so that it shows where I actually went wrong.